# Retrofit 2 callback issues with UI thread

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-handler, ui-thread

I'm making a simple material design login screen which shows a progress dialog while retrofit is acquiring the data.

I have recently upgraded to retrofit 2, so I'm quite new to this.

My code for the LoginActivity:

```
private void login(){
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting login");

        if(!validate()){
            onLoginFailure();
            return;
        }

        login_button.setEnabled(false);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String username = _usernameText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(); //all usernames are lowercase only
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        //here we handle the NWL section.

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NWL.login(username, password, this); //This runs async to UI anyway.
    }
```

And other functions in LoginActivity:

```
@BindView(R.id.login_button)
Button login_button;

 public void loginOK() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        login_button.setEnabled(true);
        toastCreator.showToastLong("Login OK");
        Log.d(TAG, "Total time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
 }
```

My code from my NetworkLogic (NWL) class:

```
public void login(String username, String password, final LoginActivity loginActivity){
    LoginUser loginUser = new LoginUser(username, password);

    Call<Username> call = apiService.login(loginUser);
    Log.d(TAG, call.toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Username>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<Username> call, Response<Username> response) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Responsecode : " + response.code());
           try {
               Thread.sleep(2000); //To test if the progressdialog actually shows up
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           if(response.code()==200){
               loginActivity.loginOK();
           } else {
               loginActivity.loginFail();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<Username> call, Throwable t) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Failed: " + t.getMessage());
           loginActivity.loginFail();
       }
   });
}
```

Now I keep getting errors such as:
- android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads (about the loginbutton)
- java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() (about the toastCreator)

I understand what is causing the issue (the async thread from retrofit 2 is doing the calls), when it should be passing the call to the ui thread.
My question here is, what is the best solution to handle this? Sure I can hack some code together with CountdownLatch and run the entire async call as a forced sync, but that's not really what I'm looking for.
Should I be using a handler? If so, what would be the best way to implement this?

All code is available: https://github.com/mathieudevos/pinkiponki-app

Looking forward to the answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, since nobody has answered the question properly, here it goes!

Using a handler and posting messages to it seems to do the trick.

In the onCreate method:

```
handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            switch (msg.what){
                case 200:
                    //Got the good response
                    loginOK();
                    break;
                case 401:
                    loginFail();
                    break;
                default:
                    loginFail();
            }
        }
    };
```

And in my networklogic class:

```
Call<Username> call = apiService.login(userObject);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Username>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<Username> call, Response<Username> response) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Responsecode: " + response.code());
           Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(response.code());
           msg.sendToTarget();

       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<Username> call, Throwable t) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Failed: " + t.getMessage());
           Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(0); //0 for errors
           msg.sendToTarget();
       }
}
```

Since this is run on the mainLooper, I can play around with my UI in any of these functions.
This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit onResponse works on UI thread, So your thread.sleep() will create problem for you.

```
 Thread.sleep(2000); //This line must not be on UI thread.
```

If you need some delay you can use handler easily.

Comment: Deleting the thread.sleep still gives issues with my login_button.setEnabled(true).
Error: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads

Comment: please send your complete stack trace.

Comment: https://github.com/mathieudevos/pinkiponki-app/blob/master/PinkiPonki/app/src/main/java/com/mattikettu/pinkiponki/LoginActivity.java

Error code (giving wrong password on purpose): http://pastebin.com/YHcxYy26